# Auto Increment Id = 0 in every submitted entry

Tags: php

Right now I am working with a mysql database table. I have created a form that will input the data. The four fields that data is being entered are `Class Caption` `Class Name` `Class Description` `Credit Hours`. I have set an auto increment `id` but every time I save a class I get an `id` that equals `0` and for the class caption I get a `.` period showing up infront. I am not sure why this issue is coming up every time I submit information into the database.

**PHP**

```
<h1>class</h1>

<?php
    include ('Resources/db_connect.php');
    $query="SELECT * FROM class";
    $result=mysql_query($query, $db_link);
if ($result){
    $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
    mysql_close();
?>

<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td><h3>id</h3></td>
<td><h3>class_caption</h3></td>
<td><h3>class_name</h3></td>
<td><h3>class_description</h3></td>
<td><h3>class_credit_hours</h3></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"class_caption");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"class_name");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"class_description");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"class_credit_hours");
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $f1; ?></td>    
<td><?php echo $f2; ?></td>    
<td><?php echo $f3; ?></td>    
<td><?php echo $f4; ?></td>    
<td><?php echo $f5; ?></td>    
</tr>

<?php
$i++;

}
}
else{
    echo "No Results Found";
    mysql_close($db_link);
}
?>
```

**Insert Form**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Class Caption: <td><input type="text" name="class_caption" size="8"><br>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Class Name: <td><input type="text" name="class_name" size="30"><br>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Class Description: <td><textarea rows="5" name="class_description" cols="50"></textarea><br>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Credit Hours: <td><input type="text" name="class_credit_hours" size="1">
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**Table Design**: [LINK](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/class_des/table_structure.php)

**QUERY**

```
CREATE TABLE class
(
    id INT,
    class_caption VARCHAR(30),
    class_name VARCHAR(30),
    class_description VARCHAR(300),
    class_credit_hours INT,
    CONSTRAINT cc_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT cc_uq UNIQUE (class_caption)
);
```

Comment: Where are you doing the INSERT?

Comment: you do know that `mysql_*` is is being deprecated gradually right? Use PDO/mysqli instead.

Comment: @itachi i know my host doesnt support PDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the auto increment defined?
Shouldn't there be something like :

```
CREATE TABLE class
(
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,...
```